# How to use Facebook PHP SDK with Zend Framework 2

Tags: facebook-php-sdk, zend-framework2

I want to be able to use the Facebook PHP SDK with the new ZEND Framework 2 platform. How to do it?

Zend Framework 2 is quite different as previous version ZF1.

When I try the standard PHP in the main application controller IndexController':

```
require_once("facebook.php");

class IndexController extends AbstractActionController
{

    public $facebook;

    public function  __construct() {

        $this->facebook = new Facebook(array(
                'appId'  => 'appId',
                'secret' => 'secret_key'
        ));

    }

    /*
    ...
    */

}
```

I get following error: Fatal error: Cannot redeclare class Facebook in /../module/Application/src/Application/Controller/Facebook.php on line 160

Comment: Can you be more specific ? asking these kind of question will not get answered unless you tell where did you got stock

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can't help you specifically on the difference between ZF1 & ZF2 but a simple search in google gave me [this result](https://github.com/widmogrod/zf2-facebook-module), I think because ZF autoloads classes and you tried to require it again they are in conflict.

Comment: Hi Roni! I tried the link you posted and is not working.
So I finally was able to figure it out by myself:
https://github.com/kuzmar/ZF2-Facebook-SKD-Module

One more thing: could you please lift the ban so I will be able to post questions?

Comment: @rob - Question bans usually happen automatically.. It has nothing to do with this specific user... You should have received a link in the ban message with details on how/what you can do to lift the ban...

Answer (score 1):

According to that error message the problem is that you now have two classes called Facebook in that namespace. Try ensuring you only have one class called Facebook.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem when I needed to include the Facebook SDK in a ZF2 application.

You don't need to use any additional modules for FB SDK integration. The trick is to include the facebook library with ClassMapAutoloader, e.g.:

```
array(
    'Facebook' => 'vendor/FB/facebook.php',
)
```

Detailed instructions are [here](http://www.loneshooter.com/zend-framework-2-how-to-use-facebook-php-sdk/)

Comment: I followed those instructions, but when I put 'Facebook' in the list of modules it complains that it can't be initialized. It definitely registers the classmap file because if I change the path to garbage it outputs a map file error. If I put garbage in the class mappings though it doesn't give any complaints... so... I've no idea what to do other than hang myself right now.

Comment: Hey Shoreline, did you find a solution?