# Error: Cannot redeclare class Facebook

Tags: php, facebook, symfony, facebook-php-sdk

Like many others, I'm getting the following error when using the default facebook.php file:

```
Fatal error: Cannot redeclare class Facebook in C:\wamp\www\symfony\src\Acme\MainBundle\Controller\facebook.php on line 160
```

Line 160 is the end of the class declaration in facebook.php

### Here is my code:

```
    require_once("Facebook.php");
    $config = array();
    $config['appId'] = '479914672022732';
    $config['appId'] = 'd451285c1c38126710980d2b7f2b43b4';
    //everything works just fine up until here. This causes the error.
    $facebook = new Facebook($config);
```

How can I fix this error?

### What I've tried:

ensured there are no other facebook classes in the project

changing require_once, include_once, etc.

using an if statement to not require the file or declare the facebook variable if it already exists

### Research:

[How to use Facebook PHP SDK with Zend Framework 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13030026/how-to-use-facebook-php-sdk-with-zend-framework-2)

as well as many other posts, but they were relating to frameworks like drupal, zend, wordpress, etc.

### What I've learned:

A good method of using the facebook php sdk is by using composer to bring it into the project. Then when defining the $facebook variable. Make sure to use a backslash, so its:

```
$facebook = new /Facebook($config);
```

Comment: Have you tried *without* the `require_once` statement?

Comment: Yes. I've tried require_once, require, include, and include_once

Comment: No, I said **without**

Comment: Sorry I misunderstood what you said. I'll try that now. Thanks for the suggestions

Comment: I tried it without the require statement. It found facebook.php by itself, but then facebook.php couldn't find BaseFacebook. I tried tweaking both facebook.php and base_facebook.php. I could fix one issue, but one issue led to another. I'm pretty sure that's not the right way to go about it.

Comment: Try installing it using composer. The package is called `facebook/php-sdk`. Then you don't need a require and autoloading should be handled for you.

Comment: What is the other location that Facebook is being pulled in from? Do you have a symfony bundle that's pulling it in separately?

Comment: Tomas, I'll try that out. That sounds very promising. Thanks so much.

Comment: Tomas, your solution was very helpful. using composer to get the facebook php sdk worked. then to use it i had to make sure to use a "/" in front of facebook. $facebook = new /Facebook($parameters); Thanks! if you make a new reply I'd like to mark you as the solution.

Comment: Why do you have two $config['appId'] ??

Comment: it should be $config['secret']. I'm not entirely sure how that happened, but it's right in my code.Thanks for pointing that out Ryoku

Comment: have you tried WITHOUT require_once("Facebook.php"); ?

Comment: capser, crisp suggested that already. This problem has been resolved by tomas.pecserke. I can't mark him as the solution though since he only posted a reply to my original post.

Answer (score 0):

Why try it if a bundle does this for you?

Check:

[FOSFacebookBundle](https://github.com/FriendsOfSymfony/FOSFacebookBundle)